# installed nautilus and cinnamon files on the appcenter, now i can't delete them

Tags: release-hera, applications, appcenter, files, filesystem

I just downloaded nautilus files and cinnamon files to try them out. I wanted to test the desktop on nautilus, and i didn't really have a reason to download cinnamon but i did. But now, I can't delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nameoftheapp
```

For example:

```
sudo apt remove --purge nautilus
sudo apt remove --purge cinnamon
```